# Match all the words of an exact length separated by comma

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've a string in this format:

```
text = "Louis,Edward,John,Billy,Don,Dean"
```

I'd like to extract from this string, all the names whose length is between 2 and 4. If I've just one name in the list, there is no comma:

```
text = "Louis"
```

I'm trying with this regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('(\w{2,4})(,\w{2,4})*')
search_result = pattern.findall('Louis,Edward,John,Billy,Don,Dean')
print(search_result)
```

The result is:

```
[('Loui', ''), ('Edwa', ''), ('rd', ',Bill'), ('Don', ',Dean')]
```

while I expect to be:

```
['John', 'Don','Dean']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Billy" has length 5. Are you sure this should be in the result?

Comment: @coldspeed you are right, edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixing your regex, you can add word boundaries around `\w{2,4}`.

```
re.findall(r'\b\w{2,4}\b', text)
# ['John', 'Don', 'Dean']
```

Or,

```
p = re.compile(r'\b\w{2,4}\b')
p.findall(text)
# ['John', 'Don', 'Dean']
```

This will ensure that names length 2-4 are matched only if they are not part of a larger string.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx seems unnecessary for this task. You can try splitting the string on commas, then filtering it with a list comprehension:

```
names = 'Louis,Edward,John,Billy,Don,Dean'

result = [name for name in names.split(',') if 2 <= len(name) <= 4]
```

---

```
['John', 'Don', 'Dean']
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, but I need to achieve this with regex.

Comment: @coldspeed Oh, sorry! I didn't see it when I was editing the answer. Should I remove it?

Comment: @coldspeed Okay, I rolled it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
text = "Louis,Edward,John,Billy,Don,Dean"
result = list(filter(lambda x:2<=len(x)<=4,text.split(",")))
```

[You can try it here](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsMgEADQPV8hTgpHh7RTiUtJlpKfsGjJwfUUvVDz9ZbQ/fHyIVvia@8Smyin9Jp2rLCEry8BnmljeCDRAXNimKNnPZRYdzotYRXzRpJYDPnPK3jV7uPkKLJpdnI3ONNLzYRiNGhr7ZALsph/YXv/AQ)